# A hybrid version of TableViewer and TreeViewer

Tags: java, swt, tableviewer, treeviewer

[image]

I need a Java SWT widget that can help me achieve what is shown in box 3. It should have the indentation of a tree but not display the twistie. Have tried NatTable too.. but it doesn't help.

Else, are there any hacks to achieve this?

Comment: So you only want the indentation, but nothing else that the `TreeViewer` gives you over the `TableViewer`?

Comment: `TreeViewer` has an `updatePlus` method, I guess you could override it achieve what you want.

Comment: @svasa `updatePlus` only set the expanded / collapsed state, it does not actually draw the twistie - the native control does that.

Comment: In NatTable you can register a tree painter with empty icons as a hack

Comment: @greg-449 you are right, It was just a guess.

Comment: @Baz you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Dirk I am not allowed to use nebula widgets

Comment: @greg-449 when you mean the native control, can i do some amendments there?

Comment: The native control is the tree API used by the particular OS to draw a tree. It is different from each OS, for example on Mac OS X `NSOutlineView` is used, on Linux it will be some GTK API and something else again on Windows. So you could only change this if the native control API supports turning off the twistie and you would have to have a detailed knowledge of the API and SWT for each platform you are interested in.

Comment: Well, apart from using space (highly not allowed), can i indent content in the TableViewer like a treeViewer?

Answer (score 1):

As you are not allowed to use Nebula widgets and the customization of the native widgets below on OS layer is not recommended (it might break with each OS update) the only solution I would see is to use custom drawing. Maybe by painting over the icons.

How to do custom drawing in a table or tree is explained here: https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html